# Powershell Command - get-appvclientpackage

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, powershell, package

I am using the Powershell command (`get-appvclientpackage`) in Visual Studio. When this is executed, all the details regarding the package are displayed.

Now, I only want the name of the package to be displayed. Can this be done?

Comment: I don't know that specific cmdlet and can't test it here, but I expect it's returning an object with a number of fields, "name" being one of them. First, try `get-appvclientpackage | get-member`. This will show you the fields of the object. Once you've found the name, you just need to do `get-appvclientpackage | select-object <field name>`(Replace <field name> with the appropriate name)

Comment: You can actually push it one step further and do `get-appvclientpackage | select-object -expandproperty <field name>`